# select2 using ajax by templateSelection. It is in BS tab when I switch the tab my select2 selected value as empty. How to show the selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Please help me out of this.
select2 using ajax by templateSelection code is below:

```
function formatApproverSelection(repo) {
    if(repo.selected && repo.text != "") {
        return repo.text;
    }
    else if(repo.employee_name == null) {
       return "Select the offer letter approval"
    }
    else {
      return repo.employee_name + ' - ' + repo.emp_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add here your HTML code